# Why does this one DropDownListFor work, and this other one doesnt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to learn mvc, and after much struggle I finally got a `DropDownListFor` to work as intented. Here is the working `Dropdownlistfor`.

> Working ViewModel

```
public partial class get_preKschedule_Result
    {
        public string start_time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> lunch_minutes { get; set; }
        public string dismiss_time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> headct { get; set; }
        public byte format { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> days_per_week { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

`format` is the type of preK program the school is enrolled in. The values are stored 1-10 in the database so the `DropDownListFor` will need all values and text. Here is the View.

> Working View

```
@model  DirectoryMVC.Models.get_preKschedule_Result

@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Head Start", Value = "6" });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Four Year Old At Risk", Value = "7" });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Integrated Special Ed", Value = "8" });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Reverse Mainstream Special Ed", Value = "9" });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All Other District Special Ed", Value = "10" });

}
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.format, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", listItems.Where(x => x.Value == Model.format.ToString())))
    @*listItems*@
</div>
```

I don't know if there is an easier way, but this is the way I finally got it to work. So when I do this exact same process for this next ViewModel it didn't work! **Edit** The administrator dropdown for title is not selecting any value, or setting any text. I will also list everything I tried. I am 100 percent sure that the data returned is correct I have verified in the watch that the models property `title` evaluates to true when I compare it to SelectListItems value.

> Non-Working ViewModel

```
public partial class get_administrators_Result
{
    public int admin_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

> Non-Working View

```
@model  DirectoryMVC.Models.get_administrators_Result

@{ 
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr." });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dr.", Value = "Dr." });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "Mrs." });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Rev.", Value = "Rev." });
}

<div class="col-md-1"> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", listItems.Where(x=>x.Value == Model.title)))
</div>
```

I have even tried

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", Model.title))
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", (object)Model.title))
```

and every other combination I can think of with the lambda `(m=> m, ...`

**Edit**
I have been asked for the action as well. This action returns the Index.cshtml. And both the working view and non-working view are EditorTemplates on that page. I am not going to condense the Action or the View.

> ActionMethod

```
public ActionResult Index(string district)
        {
            getbuilding1_Result bldgResult = de.getbuilding1(district, "1844", null).FirstOrDefault();
            List<get_bldg_contact_email_Result> studentExchangeContact = de.get_bldg_contact_email(district, "1844", 1).ToList();
            get_grades_offered_Result gradesOffered = de.get_grades_offered(district, "1844").FirstOrDefault();
            get_daily_schedule_Result dailyResult = de.get_daily_schedule(district, "1844", 2017).FirstOrDefault();
            List<get_administrators_Result> adminResult = de.get_administrators(district, "1844", 0).ToList();
            List<getabbrev_Result> abbrResult = de.getabbrev().ToList();
            get_total_school_days_Result schoolDays = de.get_total_school_days(district, "1844", 2017).FirstOrDefault();
            List<get_preKschedule_Result> kinderPreKResult = de.get_session_schedule(district, "1844", 2017).ToList();

            if (studentExchangeContact.Count < 1) { studentExchangeContact.Add(new get_bldg_contact_email_Result()); }

            MergeBuilding mergeBuild = new MergeBuilding();
            mergeBuild.schoolDays = schoolDays;
            mergeBuild.gradesOffered = gradesOffered;
            mergeBuild.dailyResult = dailyResult;
            mergeBuild.bldgResult = bldgResult;
            mergeBuild.studentExchangeContact = studentExchangeContact;
            mergeBuild.abbrResult = abbrResult;
            mergeBuild.adminResult = adminResult;
            mergeBuild.kinderPreKResult = kinderPreKResult;

            return View(mergeBuild);
        }
```

> Containing View / Parent View? Whatever the term is.

```
@using DirectoryMVC.Models

@model MergeBuilding
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Building";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    List<get_preKschedule_Result> prekSession = Model.kinderPreKResult.Where(x => x.format >= 6).ToList();
    List<get_preKschedule_Result_Result> kinderSession = Model.kinderPreKResult.Where(x => x.format <= 5).ToList();
    List<get_administrators_Result> adminy = Model.adminResult;
}

<h2>Building</h2>
<h4>@Model.bldgResult.bldg_name</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateBuilding", "Building", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.bldgResult, "_FullBuilding")
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <h4>Student Record Exchange Contact</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.studentExchangeContact.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.studentExchangeContact[i], "_StudentRecordExchange")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="radio-inline"> Which email address do you want printed in the directory?</p>
            <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.bldgResult.print_email, "b") Building Email</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.bldgResult.print_email, "p") Principal/Head Teacher</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Administrators</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            First name
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Last name
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Admin code
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Email
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            @for (var i = 0; i < adminy.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="row">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => adminy[i],  "_Administrator")
                    </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.gradesOffered, "_Grades")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.bldgResult, "_BuildingProperties")
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.dailyResult, "_DailySchedule")
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.schoolDays, "_TotalSchoolDays")
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <h4>Preschool Sessions</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Start
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Lunch Minutes
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Dismiss
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Days Per Week
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    PreK Program
                </div>
            </div>
            @for (var i = 0; i < prekSession.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => prekSession[i], "_PreKSession")

                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Proof of the data matching the value. I had changed the variable name to `listItems2` in the non-working view in case there was some issue there.

[image: watch values from visual studio showing equality compare returning true]

**Edit 3**

This seems to be a Visual studio / .Net issue. I can't step into the accessing of the title property. Intellisense doesn't pick up the title property of the model as well.

When I type `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.` I get no intellisense for `title`. The working `DropDownListFor` will step through for the `format` property, but it also doesn't have intellisense in the lambda.

When I was originally stepping through, I was looking at `this.Model.title` which had the proper value. But the lambda expression does not step into accessing the property!

Comment: You already have a `List<SelectListItem>` - why in the world are you using `new SelectList(...)` to create another identical one - its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.format, listItems)`. And its the value of the property your binding to that determines what is selected - setting the `Selected` property of `SelectList` is ignored

Comment: And you have not explained what is not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have edited the question, but what is wrong is the dropdown is not selecting anything or setting any text. It's just defaulting to  `Mr.` since it is the first.

Comment: If its selecting the first option, then it means the value of `title` is either `"Mr."` or the value of `title` does not match any of the option values (and it need to be an exact match - no whitespace for example)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is not selecting the first one because the value is Mr. I have confirmed it isn't, I have stepped through and debugged the first model.title value is Rev. and I have done an equality compare on the SelectList item it is also Rev. and returned true.

Comment: @christopherclark: SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object) :Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text field, and a selected value. I think your Model.title value is null or not matching with any value of the list.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your suggestion to make `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.format, listItems)` worked for the preKschedule View but not the administrators.  I used `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.title, listItems)`

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui it is. I have debugged, the data value field exactly matches with an equality compare on the selected value. 100 percent.

Comment: If the value of `title` is `"Rev."` then the last option will be selected unless you have something else that is changing the value

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are seeing everything in the view. Nothing is changing it. I have the breakpoint on the DropDownListFor. I have captured the model.title and selectList Value and done a compare. I can't be wrong about that. I'm doing exactly the same thing in the preKschedule view...

Comment: @christopherclark  :Can you please also share the code for action method  for the both view

Comment: Your mean like [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AaEI7t) - or perhaps not because it does select the correct option :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes this is correct way to select predefined option using model binding. you don't need to create new list again when you have already created one.

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui Code Has been updated to add action and containing view.

Comment: Based on you edit you going about this the wrong way (and its not clear which of your templates contains that model). You `EditorTemplates` need be be named to match the name of the class, for example `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/get_daily_schedule_Result.cshtml` and then in the view its `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.bldgResult)`

Comment: And ditto for loops - the `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and you do not use a `for` loop - for example its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => prekSession)`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you can explicitly state which editor template you want to use. Notice the PreK one is also different than the model. I have also added image of equality comparison, in edit.

Comment: Yes you can (if you do not want it to bind correctly :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke `EditorFor()` only takes one model, not a list. You must for loop to build out each row.

Comment: It does take a list!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke The model has to be properly bound because when I step through it, the model has all the right values. It also properly builds out the markup. I will make your suggested changes with editor naming, and making the viewModel for administrator take a list.

Comment: @christopherclark you mean you want it to preselect Rev. but instead its selecting Mr.  right?

Comment: @Usman it is not selecting `Mr.` it shows it as the text because it is the first. but the developer tools shows nothing for selected. Also see edit 3

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have made the necessary changes, and it still does not work. See my 3rd edit for what I think is the root of the problem.