# MVC How do I set value of the Model behind DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `DropDownList` that didn't work as a `DropDownListFor` so it has been abandoned.

How do I attach a DropDownList to be the model value for the item in the view. Here is my code.

```
@model  DirectoryMVC.Models.get_administrators_Result

@{ 
    List<SelectListItem> listItems2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr." });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dr.", Value = "Dr." });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "Mrs." });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Rev.", Value = "Rev." });

    foreach (SelectListItem li2 in listItems2)
    {
        if (li2.Value == this.Model.title)
        {
            li2.Selected = true;
        }
    }

    ViewBag.Titles = listItems2;

    List<SelectListItem> admins = ViewBag.JobTitle;
    foreach (SelectListItem item in admins)
    {
        if (this.Model.admin_code.TrimEnd(' ') == item.Value)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Selected = false;
        }
    }
    ViewBag.JobTitle = admins;
}
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.admin_id)

        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.DropDownList("Titles")

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.first_name)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.last_name)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"> @Html.DropDownList("JobTitle")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email)
        </div>
```

In the controller, admin_code, and admin_title. The two dropdowns are null. The values are properly selected when looking at the page, but they are not properly mapped to the model on form post.

Comment: Why didn't it work when using `@Html.DropDownListFor`? You don't need to set the selected value of `Titles` drop down yourself if you want to bind it to a model property so you can avoid `foreach (SelectListItem li2 in listItems2)` altogether. Use `@Html.DropDownList("title", ViewBag.Titles )` for that. [This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/) might help you.

Comment: You are not providing any values to the `Html.DropDownList` function.. so I'm not sure how you are seeing any values in the rendered page at all.

Comment: @granit you can see my previous question here. I abandoned it all together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520636/why-does-this-one-dropdownlistfor-work-and-this-other-one-doesnt

Comment: @granit Use `@Html.DropDownList("title", ViewBag.Titles )` did not work. `"title"` is the model property, `"Titles"` is the viewbag. The error received when trying your code is `"The ViewData item that has the key 'title is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'`

Comment: @SamAxe you can see I loop through List and set the selected value to true if it matches the property value, and the SelectListItem value.

Comment: @christopherclark That seems not to work in MVC 4. Have you tried changing the viewbag from `Titles` to `title` to match the name of the property in `get_administrators_Result` and then use `@Html.DropDownList("title")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is still the model you are using:

```
public partial class get_administrators_Result
{
    public int admin_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply need to change `@Html.DropDownList("Titles")` to `@Html.DropDownList("Title")`. For model binding to work, form elements need to have the same names as model properties.

As a side note, you really ought to be using `DropDownListFor` - I get that it didn't quite work for you the first time around, but I strongly advise revisiting it.

Comment: This needs to be changed as well: `ViewBag.Titles = listItems2;` to `ViewBag.Title = listItems2;` and the property must be `Title` as well, right?

Comment: Good point. Although, personally, I prefer to specify the IEnumerable being used by a DropDownListFor, rather than rely on a similarly named ViewBag item - these _magical_ relationships are too fickle imo.

Comment: @sleeyuen I'm finding these things can be very fickle. DropDownListFor was a nightmare, and this solution worked.